# RSA Encryption code in C help needed

Tags: c, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to tun this code about encryption and decryption using RSA feed in C language, but I just can't get it to work. It does ask for the two prime numbers and also the message, but does not display either the ciphered or the deciphered text.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

long int p,q,n,t,flag,e[100],d[100],temp[100],j,m[100],en[100],i;
char msg[100];
int prime(long int);
void ce();
long int cd(long int);
void encrypt();
void decrypt();
void main()
{

    printf("\nENTER FIRST PRIME NUMBER\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&p);
    flag=prime(p);
    if(flag==0)
    {
        printf("\nWRONG INPUT\n");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nENTER ANOTHER PRIME NUMBER\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&q);
    flag=prime(q);
    if(flag==0||p==q)
    {
        printf("\nWRONG INPUT\n");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nENTER MESSAGE\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf_s("%s",msg);
    for(i=0;msg[i]!=NULL;i++)
        m[i]=msg[i];
    n=p*q;
    t=(p-1)*(q-1);
    ce();
    printf("\nPOSSIBLE VALUES OF e AND d ARE\n");
    for(i=0;i<j-1;i++)
        printf("\n%ld\t%ld",e[i],d[i]);
    encrypt();
    decrypt();
    getch();
}
int prime(long int pr)
{
    int i;
    j=sqrt((double)pr);
    for(i=2;i<=j;i++)
    {
        if(pr%i==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
void ce()
{
    int k;
    k=0;
    for(i=2;i<t;i++)
    {
        if(t%i==0)
            continue;
        flag=prime(i);
        if(flag==1&&i!=p&&i!=q)
        {
            e[k]=i;
            flag=cd(e[k]);
            if(flag>0)
            {
                d[k]=flag;
                k++;
            }
            if(k==99)
                break;
        }
    }
}
long int cd(long int x)
{
    long int k=1;
    while(1)
    {
        k=k+t;
        if(k%x==0)
            return(k/x);
    }
}
void encrypt()
{
    long int pt,ct,key=e[0],k,len;
    =0;
    len=strlen(msg);
    while(i!=len)
    {
        pt=m[i];
        pt=pt-96;
        k=1;
        for(j=0;j<key;j++)
        {
            k=k*pt;
            k=k%n;
        }
        temp[i]=k;
        ct=k+96;
        en[i]=ct;
        i++;
    }
    en[i]=-1;
    printf("\nTHE ENCRYPTED MESSAGE IS\n");
    for(i=0;en[i]!=-1;i++)
        printf("%c",en[i]);
}
void decrypt()
{
    long int pt,ct,key=d[0],k;
    i=0;
    while(en[i]!=-1)
    {
        ct=temp[i];
        k=1;
        for(j=0;j<key;j++)
        {
            k=k*ct;
            k=k%n;
        }
        pt=k+96;
        m[i]=pt;
        i++;
    }
    m[i]=-1;
    printf("\nTHE DECRYPTED MESSAGE IS\n"); 
    for(i=0;m[i]!=-1;i++) 
        printf("%c",m[i]); 
}
```

Comment: secret to readable code.. PROPER INDENTATION..

Comment: Actually I don't see any excuse not to indent the code, while today, perhaps only the Notepad is not supporting auto-indentation..

Comment: What is the purpose of `=0;` at the top of the `encrypt()` function?

Comment: @errorinfinity What are your inputs? `msg[100]` seems awfully big considering you're not using a multi-precision library. There's likely some overflow happening. Have you tried to print the result as hex?

Comment: Why don't you declare `j` locally in each function where you need it instead of globally? Without a tooth comb, it's not easy to see if there are any collisions. And I understand `fflush(stdin)` to be undefined by the C standard, but sometimes implementation defined. Also, you need a dycryptation tool just to understand all those single-letter variables. Search/replace with meaningful names is a doddle compared to understanding the code today, tomorrow, next year.

Comment: `for(i=0;msg[i]!=NULL;i++) m[i]=msg[i];` didn't this generate a compiler warning? `NULL` is pointer value, not a `char` value. Anyway what do have against `strcpy()` or even `strdup()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call

```
scanf_s("%s",msg);
```

is missing the size argument. Change to

```
scanf_s("%s", msg, (unsigned)sizeof msg);
```

You are also doing this

```
for(i=0;msg[i]!=NULL;i++)
    m[i]=msg[i];
```

which generates a compiler warning, because `NULL` is pointer value, not a char value. But its biggest sin is not copying the `'\0'` string terminator. What do have against `strcpy()` or even `strdup()`?